# numbers are being concatenated instead of summed

Tags: sum, xslt-1.0

I have the following input:

```
<nodes>
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <val>1000</val>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>B</type>  
        <val>2000</val>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <val>3000</val>  
    </node>  
</nodes>
```

My goal is to get a list of unique types and sum all their vals.  I'm getting the following output:

```
<nodes>  
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <sum>10003000</sum>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>B</type>  
        <sum>2000</sum>  
    </node>  
</nodes>
```

I was expecting a sum (for type A) of 4000, but I'm getting 10003000 instead.

Here's my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:key name="type" match="/nodes/node/type/text()" use="." />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <nodes>
            <xsl:for-each select="/nodes/node/type/text()[generate-id()=generate-id(key('type',.)[1])]">
                <node>
                    <xsl:variable name="t" select="."/>
                    <type><xsl:value-of select="$t"/></type>
                    <sum>
                        <xsl:for-each select="/nodes/node[type=$t]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(number(Value))"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </sum>
                </node>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </nodes>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I obtain the results I'm looking for?  Also, some of the values to be summed contain comma(s) as a separator (e.g., 1,000).  To my knowledge, sum() doesn't handle commas. How do I address these concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just replace**:

```
<sum>
  <xsl:for-each select="/nodes/node[type=$t]">
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(number(Value))"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
</sum>
```

**with**:

```
<sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(/nodes/node[type=$t]/val)"/></sum>
```

**Here is a complete transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kType" match="type" use="."/>

 <xsl:template match="type[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kType',.)[1])]">
  <type><xsl:value-of select="."/></type>
  <sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kType',.)/../val)"/></sum>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>1000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>B</type>
        <val>2000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>3000</val>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<type>A</type>
<sum>4000</sum>
<type>B</type>
<sum>2000</sum>
```

---

**Update**:

The OP has added new requirements: the numbers can contain a comma.

**The solution below performs a two-pass transformation, where the first pass deletes any non-digit character in any `val/text()` node**.

**The second pass operates on the result of the first pass and is essentially the solution to the initial question**.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kType" match="type" use="."/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2" select=
   "$vPass1/*/*/type[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kType',.)[1])]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="val/text()[true()]">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(.,'01234567890', ''), '')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="type" mode="pass2">
  <type><xsl:value-of select="."/></type>
  <sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kType',.)/../val)"/></sum>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document (added a comma to the provided one):**

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>1,000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>B</type>
        <val>2000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>3000</val>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<type>A</type>
<sum>4000</sum>
<type>B</type>
<sum>2000</sum>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre!  I've taken a look at my entire data set and some of the values to be summed contain commas as the grouping separator for thousands (e.g., <val>1,000</val>).  Using sum() doesn't correctly handle any commas.  Any workarounds for this?

Comment: @RobShell, This is another, new question and it is rasy to answer. Please, ask your new question as a ... new question -- and let me know via a comment. Your current question is completely answered, so, please, *accept* it by clicking the check-mark next to the answer.

Comment: Dimitre, I've posted the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056913/how-to-sum-values-with-commas-using-sum

Comment: I'm using XMLSpy and it reports "Function not in namespace" on the following: select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"