# how to sum values with commas using sum()

Tags: sum, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML document:

```
<nodes>
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <val>1,000</val>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>B</type>  
        <val>2,000</val>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <val>3,000</val>  
    </node>  
</nodes>
```

My goal is to get a list of unique types and sum all their `<val>`s. I'm getting the following output:

```
<nodes>  
    <node>  
        <type>A</type>  
        <sum>3</sum>  
    </node>  
    <node>  
        <type>B</type>  
        <sum>2</sum>  
    </node>  
</nodes>
```

I was expecting a sum (for type A) of 4000, but I'm getting 3 instead.

Here's my xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
    <xsl:key name="type" match="/nodes/node/type/text()" use="." />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <nodes>
            <xsl:for-each select="/nodes/node/type/text()[generate-id()=generate-id(key('type',.)[1])]">
                <node>
                    <xsl:variable name="t" select="."/>
                    <type><xsl:value-of select="$t"/></type>
                    <sum>
                       <xsl:value-of select="sum(/nodes/node[type=$t]/val)"/>
                    </sum>
                </node>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </nodes>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any ideas on how I can sum values with commas in them using sum()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kType" match="type" use="."/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="pass2" select=
   "$vPass1/*/*/type[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kType',.)[1])]"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="val/text()[true()]">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., translate(.,'01234567890', ''), '')"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="type" mode="pass2">
  <type><xsl:value-of select="."/></type>
  <sum><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kType',.)/../val)"/></sum>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<nodes>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>1,000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>B</type>
        <val>2,000</val>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>A</type>
        <val>3,000</val>
    </node>
</nodes>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<type>A</type>
<sum>4000</sum>
<type>B</type>
<sum>2000</sum>
```

Comment: I'm using XMLSpy and it reports "Function not in namespace" on the following: select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"
Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Try removing `ext:node-set()` but leaving its argument -- I am not absolutely sure, but I think XML Spy isn't XSLT 1.0 - compliant.

Comment: @RobShell, Instead of: `<xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1)"/>` try just: `<xsl:variable name="vPass1" select="$vrtfPass1"/>`
`

Comment: @RobShell, So, did you try my suggestion? It works for me with XMLSpy.

Comment: this worked.  Thank you for your help.  Hours after I used your solution a decision was made to remove the commas from the input.  C'est la vie!!

Comment: @RobShell, You are welcome. Don't worry, the next time such a problem pops up, you'll know how to deal with it.